# How to increase Content-Length delimited message body in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-4.0

Response message: Non HTTP response message: Premature end of Content-Length delimited message body (expected: 696970; received: 351956)

> org.apache.http.ConnectionClosedException: Premature end of
>   Content-Length delimited message body (expected: 696970; received:
>   351956    at
>   org.apache.http.impl.io.ContentLengthInputStream.read(ContentLengthInputStream.java:178)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream.read(EofSensorInputStream.java:135)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream.read(EofSensorInputStream.java:148)
>     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.readResponse(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1814)
>     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPAbstractImpl.readResponse(HTTPAbstractImpl.java:446)
>     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:475)
>     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:74)
>     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1189)
>     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1178)
>     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:490)
>     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:416)
>     at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:250)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing you can "increase", the error you got indicates that you received an incomplete response (2x times less than server stated it would be).

Most likely your server is simply overloaded so it cannot deliver the content in full. Check out your application under test logs - most probably you will find the reason there.

Other things to consider:

- Set up monitoring of baseline OS health metrics on the application under test side, you can use [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/) or [SSHMon Listener](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-monitor-server-resource-utilization-with-jmeters-sshmon-listener) for this
- Enable [profiler tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_(computer_programming)) telemetry for your application for the duration of your test. The overhead should be minimal, however you will be able to collect a lot of useful information regarding slowest functions, largest objects, etc.
- If there any middleware included (load balancers, transparent proxies, databases, etc.) they need to be checked as well as in n-tier system failure or slowness of a single component can lead to malfunction.

Comment: Thank you Dmitri T. I will check this issue with once Developer

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation.